On Second time Face Authentication IOS app gets crashed ['Window was already deactivated']
Whenever I try to authenticate app second time by using face in IOS apps gets crashed error shows 'Window was already deactivated'. used below code for the face authentication.
lang-c#
var result = await BiometricAuthenticationService.Default.AuthenticateAsync(new AuthenticationRequest()
{
    Title = $"{AppResources.Pleaseauthenticateforfaceid}",
    NegativeText = $"{AppResources.Cancelauthentication}"
}, CancellationToken.None);

I tried to use initialized service as a AddTransient rather than AddSingleton also tried to initialized IBiometric service into constructor still it gets crashed on second time authentication.

Does it help? Maui app crash on IOS with 'Window was already deactivated'

@LiqunShen-MSFT No, already checked..

Do you use Plugin.Maui.Biometric?

@LiqunShen-MSFT Yes

My issue is got resolved by add below code into AppDelegate.cs file of IOS[Resource]
public override void OnActivated(UIApplication application)
  {
      (application.ConnectedScenes.AnyObject as UIWindowScene)?.Windows.FirstOrDefault()?.MakeKeyWindow();
      base.OnActivated(application);
  }

  public override void OnResignActivation(UIApplication application)
  {
      (application.ConnectedScenes.AnyObject as UIWindowScene)?.Windows.FirstOrDefault()?.MakeKeyWindow();
      base.OnResignActivation(application);
  }

as per my observation the issue is due to once authentication is done it gets somehow into Windows NSSet.
So when iOSLifecycle event from MAUI want to activate/deactivate window then use KeyWindow
Thanks for response @LiqunShen-MSFT.
